# How to set selected value of HTML select box with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a next piece of the template:

```
<select name="interest">
    <option value="seo">SEO и Блоговодство</option>
    <option value="auto">Авто</option>
    <option value="business">Бизнес</option>
    <option value="design">Дизайн</option>
    ...
```

and store resulting value in `$result['interest']`.

How can I mark `option` element as selected with PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The manual way.....

```
<select name="interest">
    <option value="seo"<?php if($result['interest'] == 'seo'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>SEO и Блоговодство</option>
    .....
```

The better way would be to loop through the interests

```
$interests = array(
    'seo' => 'SEO и Блоговодство',
    'auto' => 'Авто',
    ....
);

<select name="interest">
<?php foreach( $interests as $var => $interest ): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $var ?>"<?php if( $var == $result['interest'] ): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $interest ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape your HTML! `htmlspecialchars( $var )` is your friend

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249151/how-to-properly-escape-html-form-input-default-values-in-php

Answer (score 10):

```
<?php
$interests = array('seo' => 'SEO и Блоговодство',  'auto' => 'Aвто', 'business' => 'Бизнес', ...);
?>
<select name="interest">
<?php
foreach($interests as $k => $v) {
?>
   <option value="<?php echo $k; ?>" <?php if($k == $result['interest']) ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>><?php echo $v;?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
$list='<select name="interest">
    <option value="seo">SEO и Блоговодство</option>
    <option value="auto">Авто</option>
    <option value="business">Бизнес</option>
    <option value="design">Дизайн</option>
    ...';
echo str_replace('value="' . $result['interest'] . '"','value="' . $result['interest'] . '" selected',$list);
```

?>
This involves making a string containing your list, then using the string replace function to find the correct option and adding selected to the tag. If using XHTML you will need to use selected="selected".

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/37eb8f5a213fe5a252cd4da6712f3db0c5558ae3

Answer (score 4):

```
<select name="interest">
    <option value="seo"<?php if($result['interest'] == 'seo'){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>SEO</option>
    <option value="auto"<?php if($result['interest'] == 'auto'){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>Auto</option>
    <option value="business"<?php if($result['interest'] == 'business'){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>Business</option>
    <option value="design"<?php if($result['interest'] == 'design'){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>Design</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<select name="interest">
<option value="seo" <?php echo $result['interest'] == 'seo' ? 'selected' : ''?> >SEO и Блоговодство</option>
<option value="auto" <?php echo $result['interest'] == 'auto' ? 'selected' : ''?>>Авто</option>
<option value="business" <?php echo $result['interest'] == 'business' ? 'selected' : ''?>>Бизнес</option>
<option value="design" <?php echo $result['interest'] == 'design' ? 'selected' : ''?>>Дизайн</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get PHP to insert the `selected="selected"` attribute for the appropriate `<option>` tag, like this:

```
<?php $result=$userRow['ad_type']; ?>
           <select class="form-control" name="ad_type">
              <option <?php if($result == 'text'){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?> value="text">Text</option>
              <option <?php if($result == 'image'){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?> value="image">Image</option>
              <option <?php if($result == 'video'){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?> value="video">Video</option>
              <option <?php if($result == 'htmladsense'){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?> value="htmladsense">Html Adsense</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: This seems like a good first answer, but I've edited your answer to provide an explanation for the changes. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) might be worth reading.

Comment: When you are answering to questions don't just post the answer. Give some more information about your solution

Comment: Thanks @AlastairBrown .Sorry,Its my first time here to post answer .Next time I'll keep this thing on my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Another way ( as used in WordPress ) [Link to Wordpress code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L0) which employs reusability would be:

```
    <select name='result[interest]' style="width:400px">
        <option value='SEO' <?php selected($result['interest'], 'SEO'); ?>>SEO</option>
        <option value='AUTO' <?php selected($result['interest'], 'AUTO'); ?>>Auto</option>
    </select>
```

The selected() function determines if the value was choosen and sets the  selected option.

```
/**
 * Outputs the html selected attribute.
 *
 * Compares the first two arguments and if identical marks as selected
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @param mixed $selected One of the values to compare
 * @param mixed $current  (true) The other value to compare if not just true
 * @param bool  $echo     Whether to echo or just return the string
 * @return string html attribute or empty string
 */
function selected( $selected, $current = true, $echo = true ) {
    return __checked_selected_helper( $selected, $current, $echo, 'selected' );
}
```

The selected() function in turn calls the helper function below to compare and determine whether the value is the selected or not. It returns 'selected=selected' or ''.

```
/**
 * Private helper function for checked, selected, disabled and readonly.
 *
 * Compares the first two arguments and if identical marks as $type
 *
 * @since 2.8.0
 * @access private
 *
 * @param mixed  $helper  One of the values to compare
 * @param mixed  $current (true) The other value to compare if not just true
 * @param bool   $echo    Whether to echo or just return the string
 * @param string $type    The type of checked|selected|disabled|readonly we are doing
 * @return string html attribute or empty string
 */
function __checked_selected_helper( $helper, $current, $echo, $type ) {
    if ( (string) $helper === (string) $current ) {
        $result = " $type='$type'";
    } else {
        $result = '';
    }

    if ( $echo ) {
        echo $result;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep your scripting DRY and clean by setting up an array to contain your option data.  Loop through the array and print the data into a template string with placeholders to avoid ugly, clumsy interpolation, concatenation, and inline conditions.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8ecDR))

```
$interests = [
    'seo' => 'SEO и Блоговодство',
    'auto' => 'Aвто',
    'business' => 'Бизнес',
    'design' => 'Дизайн',
];
$selected = 'business';

echo '<select name="interest">';
foreach ($interests as $value => $text) {
    printf(
        '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
        $value,
        $selected === $value ? ' selected' : '',
        $text
    );
}
echo '</select>';
```

For anyone who puts in the extra effort to produce line-separated options with appropriate tabbing, there are a few ways to add tabs and newlines while printing in PHP, but I'll not demonstrate them here.

Answer (score 0):

Simple short hand method would be

```
//after pulling your content from database
$value = interest['value'];
<option value="seo" <?php echo ($value == "seo") ? 'selected = "selected"' : '' ;?> >SEO и Блоговодство</option>
...
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to write anything.
Just type the below code

```
            `<div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Blog Trending Or Not ?</label><br>
                <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01"  name="interest">
                    
                    <option value="seo"<?php if($row['is_trending']=="seo"){echo "selected";} ?>>SEO и Блоговодство</option>
                    <option value="auto"<?php if($row['is_trending']=="auto"){echo "selected";} ?>>Авто</option>
                    <option value="business"<?php if($row['is_trending']=="business"){echo "selected";} ?>>Бизнес</option>
                    <option value="design"<?php if($row['is_trending']=="design"){echo "selected";} ?>>Дизайн</option>
                </select>
            </div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I don't see any of the existing answers doing is handling the actual default case (i.e. you want something selected even if $result['interest'] is empty). Let's say you wanted "auto" to be the default on first load of the form. In this case, you might do,

```
<?php
$value = $result['interest'];
?>
<select name="interest">
    <option <?php if($value == 'seo'): ?>selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>value="seo">SEO и Блоговодство</option>
    <option <?php if($value == '' || $value == 'auto'): ?>selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>value="auto">Авто</option>
    <option <?php if($value == 'business'): ?>selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>value="business">Бизнес</option>
    <option <?php if($value == 'design'): ?>selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>value="design">Дизайн</option>
    ...
```