# HTML Select Box, selected data from servlet

Tags: html, jsp, select

Good day!

I am having a problem with the select box in html. I am on the EDIT portion of my simple CRUD project and before users can edit, the chosen data will be shown first and I retrieved it in the database through the servlet.

Now I want the data I retrieve be the one SELECTED (default) in my select box. `${product.category}`

```
<select size="1" name="category">
        <option value ="1">Dogs</option>
        <option value ="2">Cats</option>
        <option value ="5">Others</option>
</select>
```

I tried inserting it like this but it doesn't work.

```
<select size="1" name="category" selected=${product.category}>
        <option value ="1">Dogs</option>
        <option value ="2">Cats</option>
        <option value ="5">Others</option>
</select>
```

I want to do something like this.. If (${product.category}==1), selected=option 1...

I've seen something like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747212/html-select-box-set-the-option-on-selected-with-help-php) in one of the forums but it is in PHP format. How can I do it using JSP?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `selected` attribute has to go on the HTML `<option>` element and it should **only** be set when the option value matches. Most elegant way is to use the conditional operator `?:`.

```
<select name="category">
    <option value="1" ${product.category == '1' ? 'selected' : ''}>Dogs</option>
    <option value="2" ${product.category == '2' ? 'selected' : ''}>Cats</option>
    <option value="5" ${product.category == '5' ? 'selected' : ''}>Others</option>
</select>
```

Better would be if you have the items in some `List` or `Map`. E.g. a `List<Category>` where `Category` has `id` and `name` properties.

```
<select name="category">
    <c:forEach items="${categories}" var="category">
        <option value="${category.id}" ${product.category == category.id ? 'selected' : ''}>${category.name}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

This way you don't need to repeat the same thing for all options.