# What is onload() function for forms or select?

Tags: javascript, jsp, parameter-passing

I'm trying to find a function in JavaScript that is called everytime when a `<form>` or `<select>` is created. Does anyone have a idea?

I want something like:

```
<body onload="jsFunction();">
```

More exactly, I need to make a <select> that will be included in many pages, and I want everytime this is loaded, to select one of it's values based on a request variable. So the function that will make the selection must called from this included script and must be included in this script.

I'm using JSP on the server side

Comment: @GG I was very hurried. I beg your pardon. Thanks

Comment: Are those forms and selects created by JavaScript or by JSP? If by JSP (and seems so, because using `onload` would otherwise be illogical), why don't you just use JSP to prefill/preselect the values?

Comment: I need to select the value based on the request parameters, and from what I know, the <option> does not have such an option. It has "selected" option, but this is not feet for what I need.

Comment: Uh well, what do you need then? `selected` is exactly what you need. Or did you *actually* have trouble figuring how to set it programmatically based on a request parameter? See also for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298049/html-select-box-selected-data-from-servlet/5298070#5298070

Comment: @BalusC: The selected value doesn't take true and false values. See the equinoxel's example.

Comment: You should also not set true or false. You should set the whole attribute only when the value matches. See also the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @BalusC: Thank yoou! I didn't know that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes no sense. Just set the whole `selected` attribute programmatically based on the request parameter. Here's an example:

```
<select name="foo">
    <option value="bar" ${param.foo == 'bar' ? 'selected' : ''}>Bar</option>
    <option value="baz" ${param.foo == 'baz' ? 'selected' : ''}>Baz</option>
    <option value="waa" ${param.foo == 'waa' ? 'selected' : ''}>Waa</option>
</select>
```

or if you have it in a collection:

```
<select name="foo">
  <c:forEach items="${foos}" var="foo">
    <option value="${foo}" ${param.foo == foo ? 'selected' : ''}>${foo}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

The same is true for normal inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="bar" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.bar)}" />
```

*(the `fn:escapeXml()` is there to prevent XSS attacks)*

Answer (score 0):

You could try the "selected" attribute in the option you want to select by default (like suggested [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)). If you prefer javascript, you'll need to use something like jquery to select select (or populate and select) your  tag.

For reference:

```
<select>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option selected="selected">Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: that's not good. I need to select the option based on some request variables. For example: if requestVariables.car == a then Volvo; if requestVariables.car == b then Saab; and so on...