# php dropdown select error

Tags: php, forms, select, drop-down-menu

I have the following code and it insert the necessary data to the database perfectly. but the problem is that when i want to implement select="select".. so that if the customer return he will see what he choose from the dropdown menu...how can i do that, any idea...

```
<pre>
<?php
//array generated from mysql to feed first dropdown menu.
$newOptions = array();
    foreach ($input as $option) {
        $wclID = $option['desc'];
        $nameF = $option['fame'];
        $nameL = $option['lname'];
        $id = $option['ID'];
        $newOptions[$wclID][$id] = $nameL." ".$nameF;
    }

//second array for second dropdown menu
$array = array('ent','res');    
?>


   <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <form  id="checkEnt" name="che" method="post" action="com.php?ID=<?=$ID?>">
                <input type="hidden" value="che" name="ent">
                <table class="table table-striped span10">
                    <tbody>
                        <? foreach ($newOptions as $wclID => $list) {  ?>
                            <tr><td width="5%">
                                    <h5><?=$wclID?> AA</h5>
                                </td>
                                <td width="10%">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="inputWei"><?=_('Boy')?></label>  
                                    <select class="input-xlarge" id="input" name="drop[0][]">   
                                        <option value=""><?=_('[select]')?></option>
                                        <?php 
                                            foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
                                            ?><option value="<?=$key?>"><?=$value?></option>

                                            <?php    } ?>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td width="10%">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="inputWei"><?=_('Res')?></label>
                                    <select class="input-xlarge" id="drop" name="drop[1][]">
                                        <option value=""><?=_('[select]')?></option>
                                        <?php
                                         foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                                            ?><option value="<?=$value?>"><?=$value?></option>

                                            <?php } ?>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                              <?
                            }
                        ?> 

                            <tr><td colspan="3">
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type=reset class="btn btn-danger"><?=_('Reset')?></button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" ID="btnSave"><?=_('Save')?></button>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr> 


                    </tbody>
                </table> 
            </form>   
        </div>
    </div>
</pre>
```

Comment: so there actually is no error?

Comment: What is going on with your form action?  Your PHP declaration is part of the action statement.

Comment: ohhh, sorry for saying error...question..how could i implement the select="selected" attribute...on this code?

Comment: what the action does is send the data to mysql table and properly saved. i use pdo function to achieve this...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747212/html-select-box-set-the-option-on-selected-with-help-php

Answer (score 2):

I recently did something similar to this. This is for data that is coming back from the database correct? If so then I would implement something similar to this.

On the option tags I would try an if statement to see what is in the database and then if it is call the selected=selected

```
<option value="Something" <? if(in_array('Something',$nameofArray)) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Something</option>
```

or in your case you might want to try

```
<?foreach ($list as $key => $value) {?>
    <option value="$value" <? if($value) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>$value</option>

 <?}?>
```

Comment: which array we are taking about, in_array('Something',$nameofArray) could u please elaborate

Comment: That was just an example. this in_array is where your information coming from the database should be. So in your case it would just be $value so if your value is there then it will be selected. Make sense?

Comment: $html_form .= '<option value="'.$value.'"'. if($value) echo 'selected="selected">'.$value.'</option>'; why i get error

Comment: hi zazvorniki, could you please see the above code and suggest please how could i insert selected="selected" attribute..Please?

Comment: i see this code....of yours..<?foreach ($list as $key => $value) {?>
    <option value="$value" <? if($value) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>$value</option>

 <?}?>

Comment: <label class="control-label" for="inputWei"><?=_('Res')?></label>
                                    <select class="input-xlarge" id="drop" name="drop[1][]">
                                        <option value=""><?=_('[select]')?></option>
                                        <?php
                                         foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                                            ?><option value="<?=$value?>"><?=$value?></option>

                                            <?php } ?>
                           </select>

Comment: I was looking at the above code and have edited my answer. I can only give you so much to work with the rest you have to figure out on your own because I don't have access to all your code. You are also going to have to say what error you are getting and what the behavior is if there is no error. Is the second drop down just not working or is there something different with it then the first? From what it looks like they both seem the same to me.

Answer (score -1):

Use the "selected" attribute of the option tag:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Comment: but how? i just put like this <option value="<?=$key?>" select="selected"><?=$value?></option>