# how to preserve data in <select> element

Tags: php, forms, input

For multiple steps form I preserve entered value in `<input>` elements with this code:

```
<input name="city" type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : '' ?>"/>
```

but I don't know how to implement it for `<select>` elements in order to preserve selected option.

Comment: What does your `<select>` look like and how is it created? Does PHP put it together?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Select Box: set the option on selected with help PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747212/html-select-box-set-the-option-on-selected-with-help-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "selected" to the desired option:

```
<select>
  <option value="a" <?php echo ($_POST['select'] == 'a') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>a</option>;
  <option value="b" <?php echo ($_POST['select'] == 'b') ? 'selected' : '' ?>>b</option>
  <option value="c" <?php echo ($_POST['select'] == 'c') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>c</option>
</select>
```

Or, if you create your select with a loop, do it once for every options:

```
<?php $list = array('a', 'b', 'c'); ?>

<select>
<?php foreach($list as $value): ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>" <?php echo ($_POST['select'] == $value) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $value; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```