# Keep option selected

Tags: php, html, forms, foreach

I have a selectbox with some values, i inserted those values inside an array.

Now i want to select some specific option, and keep the option selected even when the page reloads.

```
$logos =array('logo1', 'logo2', 'logo3');
echo '
<td class="jofftd">
<label>Platform</label>
   <select name="searchpt">
   <option value="0">All</option>
      ';
      foreach ($logos as $value)
      {
      echo '
      <option value="'.$value.'">' .$value . '</option>
      ';
      }
      echo '
   </select>
</td>';
```

I would need to do something like this:

```
foreach ($logos as $value)
      {
      echo '
      <option';

      if ($value == $value) echo 'selected="selected"'; 

      echo 'value="'.$value.'">' .$value . '</option>

      ';
      }
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: which value you want to be defaultly selected??

Comment: and what is this `$value == $value`

Comment: "All" is already the defaultly selected

Comment: no what i'am asking is which value in the drop down box should be autoselected? dropdown can have only one option selected at a time

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747212/html-select-box-set-the-option-on-selected-with-help-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a POST method form, the code would look something like this (note: not tested)

```
  foreach ($logos as $value)
    {
        $selected = ($value == $_POST['searchpt']) ? ' selected' : '';
        echo '<option'. $selected . ' value="'.$value.'">' .$value . '</option>';
    }
```

Comment: I understand the logic, but its giving me this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' selected'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, you're missing at least one space character:

```
 <option';
      if ($value == $value) echo 'selected="selected"';
```

This will produce

```
 <optionselected="selected"
```

which is not exactly valid HTML.

Plus, `$value==$value` will always be true, so even if you had proper spacing in the tags, you'd be marking **ALL** of the options as selected. You need to compare the `$value` from the loop against the value from the original form, e.g.

```
if ($value == $_POST['field_from_previous_form'}) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

$value == $value will be always true and it will always add selected = "selected"

use string concatenation to form select form field.

```
    <?php 

$logos =array('logo1', 'logo2', 'logo3');

$value = 'logo1';

$str = '<select name="searchpt"><option value="0">All</option>';
foreach ($logos as $value)
      {
      $str.='<option ';

      if ($value == 'logo1') 
      $str.=' selected="selected "'; 

      $str.=' value="'.$value.' ">' .$value . ' </option> ';
      }
$str.='</select>';

echo $str;

?>
```

Hope this code snippet will solve your problem