# Retrieve value from DB and display in a drop down on edit form in php

Tags: php

This script does not display the DB value in a drop down on the edit form.

```
<?php
echo "<select name='assign' value=''><option>Select name</option>";
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $value = $r['name'];
    echo "<option value=" . $r['emp_id'] . ">" . $r['name'] . " if ($name=='$value')  echo 'selected = 'selected''></option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

---

It does not show any error. How it can write in a correct way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Select Box: set the option on selected with help PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747212/html-select-box-set-the-option-on-selected-with-help-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
       $echoSting = '<select name="assign"><option value="">Select name</option>'.PHP_EOL;
       while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          $value=$r['name'];
          $echoSting .= '<option value="'.$r['emp_id'].'" '.($name==$value ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$r['name'].'</option>'.PHP_EOL;
       }
       $echoSting .= '</select>'.PHP_EOL;
       echo $echoSting;
```

a side note, try looking into PDO for your database stuff : http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: In your code selected value does not echo in the field as the result, How can I echo it as selected value?

Comment: assuming the variable $name matches the value in the database, it should be selected, can you post the result of the following :                             while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
         print_r($r);
       }

Comment: It has identified correct value as a selected, But does not print in the field,

Comment: is the option selected ?

Comment: Not option selected

Comment: $echoSting .= '<option value="'.$r['emp_id'].'" '.($name==$value ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$r['name'].'</option>'.PHP_EOL;

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the fix, the option was closing before the select was outputting

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo "<select name='assign' value=''><option>Select name</option>";
                        while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            $value=$r['name'];
                            echo "<option value='.$r['emp_id'].'>'.$r['name'].' "; if ($name=='$value')  echo "selected = 'selected'";echo">$value</option>";
                        }
                        echo "</select>";
```

Comment: There is syntax error near value='.$r['emp_id'].'>'.$r['name'].' ";