# how to handle select tag on php? I want to set option on form when submitted

Tags: php, forms

this is the code

```
<select class="country" name="country" id="country" >
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Country</option>
        <option value="in" >India</option>
        <option value="jp" >Japan</option>
        </select><br/>
```

I want to set the user selected value on form when submitted. Now when user select a value it get back to "Select country" when submit button pressed.
and how can I enter full country name into database? as of now it enter the value which is "in" or "jp"?

thanks for help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set selected value of HTML select box with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747212/how-to-set-selected-value-of-html-select-box-with-php)

Comment: PHP will get what's in the `value` in the selected option. If you want another value (like the full name), then set the value to contain the full name instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommended solution is to have an array of country codes mapped to country names. This will be used to create the options using a loop, to find the full country name and to validate the user input.

**PHP**

```
$countries = array(
  'in' => 'India',
  'jp' => 'Japan',
);

$selectedCountryCode = '';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  $selectedCountryCode = isset($_POST['country']) ? $_POST['country'] : '';

  if(isset($countries[$selectedCountryCode])){
    $selectedCountryName = $countries[$selectedCountryCode];
    // insert $selectedCountryName
  } else {
    // validation error - country not found, do not insert
    $selectedCountryCode = ''; // reset because it was invalid
  }

}
```

**HTML**

This includes the select tag with the options produced from a loop. In the loop, the posted country is checked and selected if necessary. The user input will simply contain the county code `in` or `jp`, and the PHP above will map that to the full name for insertion.

```
<select class="country" name="country" id="country" >
  <option value="" disabled>Choose Country</option>
  <?php foreach($countries as $code => $countryName): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($code); ?>" <?php if($code == $selectedCountryCode){ echo 'selected'; } ?>><?php echo htmlspecialchars($countryName); ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select><br/>
```

Comment: sir how do i add an error/warning message if user select no country? let say default select is "Choose Country"? I tried add error message in else part and post it below select tag, but it didn't work.